# CakePHP 2.1: Set Message for InternalErrorException

Tags: cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.1

I have the security component in one of my comment submit forms.. 
Now, when something goes wrong, and the blackhole callback is called, I want to throw an InternalErrorException with a custom message, such as:

```
 throw new InternalErrorException('You have tried to submit a comment whose security token is either invalid or expired. Please try again by reloading the blog post and commenting again. Thank you.');
```

The thing is that the message does not get displayed in production mode (debug == 0). What do I have to do to show the message to the user instead of "An Internal Error Has Occurred"?

This is my error500.ctp: http://pastebin.com/t9NuzuqS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can probably do is overwrite the `blackHole` action of the `Security` component.

Currently you can find it in `cakephp\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\SecurityComponent`. You should create a `SecurityComponent` in your `Controller\Component` folder and overwrite this method as you wish:

```
public function blackHole(Controller $controller, $error = '') {
    if ($this->blackHoleCallback == null) {
        throw new BadRequestException(__d('cake_dev', 'The request has been black-holed'));
    } else {
        return $this->_callback($controller, $this->blackHoleCallback, array($error));
    }
}
```

You can throw the same exception with another message. 
This exceptions will be seen for users even with `debug` set to 0 [as detailed on the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Please read the below comments in order to understand why it's not the optimal one for me.

Comment: I am not talking about changing the original Security component but just to create your own one at `app` folder and overwrite this function in order to change the message to display.

Comment: Anyway, if the problem you are finding is that you can not show your exception in production mode, change it for one of the public ones from the link i posted. (BadRequestException is one)

Comment: That's actually exactly the thing I did - so I am going to accept your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

those "messages" are only for development purposes.
in live mode (debug 0) the visitor should not get any of those descriptive issue descriptions you got on your server. he wouldnt understand it anyway.
so in live mode there is only a 404/5xx thrown and thats it.
but your message will be error-logged for you (as developer) to find afterwards.

Comment: Well, I totally agree with you, but still, I want to give the user a hint how to try again with submitting a comment. It has happened that users have accidentally submitted the form in a way so that the security token was invalid. This is because of my not-so-optimal setup, but it's not debatable at the moment, anyway.

Comment: So there fore it would be good to know how to send messages to the user via exceptions, without changing the Security Component itself, as suggested above.